# Axis2 Faulty Pojo Web Service

Tags: web-services, apache-axis, pojo, fault

I have created a pojo as below.

```
package demo;
public class HelloWorld {
    public String sayHello(String name) {
        return "Hello " + name;
    }
}
```

I placed it in axis2 war and opened

```
http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/listServices.
```

Axis 2 is indicating it as faulty service

```
Faulty Services
<TOMCAT-DIR>\webapps\axis2\WEB-INF\pojo\demo\HelloWorld.class
```

But when I remove package declaration statement and place it on below location, everything works fine

```
<TOMCAT-DIR>\webapps\axis2\WEB-INF\pojo\HelloWorld.class
```

Now there are two possibilities

- Package declaration is not allowed in pojo (and I don't believe this).
- I am missing something.

Can anyone guide me?

Comment: can you show us your service.xml?

Comment: @shashankaholic I am deploying POJO based web service. It does not require any configuration file like services.xml.

Comment: you do need that check this tutorial, http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/pojoguide.html#definingservice

Comment: @shashankaholic Thanks for the link. But a pojo web servcie can also be deployed without service.xml. In this case pojo class needs to be placed inside pojo folder I described in my question. In the book "Apache Axis Web Services, 2nd Edition", Author described that when exposing a pojo as service using this method, pojo must be defined in default package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the book "Apache Axis Web Services, 2nd Edition", author described that when exposing a pojo class as a web service by dropping in into pojo folder, pojo class must be defined in default package.

When pojo class is defined some package, following link is helpful.

http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/pojoguide.html

Thanks to shashankaholic for sharing this link.